# transform DataFrame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would to transform my DataFrame using python pandas :

```
l1=['andre','Marc']
l2=[5,12]
l3=[3,64]

dfWeeks=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l1,l2,l3)), columns=['Name','22-2019','23-2019'])
dfWeeks
```

It looks like this :

```
Name 22-2019  23-2019
andre  5        3
Marc   12       64
```

I would Like to tranform it and have:

```
Name  Number  Dates
andre 5       22-2019
andre 3       23-2019
Marc  12      22-2019   
Marc  64      23-2019
```

I have tried pivot talbe or group by but I cannot manage to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), its easier:

```
df.melt('Name',var_name='Dates',value_name='Number')

    Name    Dates  Number
0  andre  22-2019       5
1   Marc  22-2019      12
2  andre  23-2019       3
3   Marc  23-2019      64
```

Or:

```
m=df.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index()
m.columns=['Name','Date','Number']
print(m)

    Name     Date  Number
0  andre  22-2019       5
1  andre  23-2019       3
2   Marc  22-2019      12
3   Marc  23-2019      64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
dfWeeks.melt(id_vars='Name')